# Emacs: dolist doesn't work with dot

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm new to Emacs. I intend to use `sh-mode` for a few for file name patterns, so I added the following lines to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(dolist (pattern '("\\.zsh$"
                   "\\.?zshrc$"
                   "zshrc\\."))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (pattern . sh-mode)))
```

However, it shows the following error:

> Symbol's function definition is void: pattern

If I use:

```
(dolist (pattern '("\\.zsh$"
                   "\\.?zshrc$"
                   "zshrc\\."))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '(pattern . sh-mode))) ;; Note the additional quote
```

`pattern` is added to the list, but not the ones in the list.

Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is the last line -- `... (pattern`  By you putting a parentheses before `pattern`, Emacs thinks you want to call a function named `pattern`.  Do a Google search for `add-to-list` `dolist` `emacs` -- you should see at least a few examples of how to do this -- e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/221449/2112489

Comment: Here is a link to a thread where lunaryorn taught me about using the backtick (instead of an apostrophe) for variables in a list, and also by placing a comma before the variable:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22440553/2112489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
(dolist (pattern '("\\.zsh$"
                   "\\.?zshrc$"
                   "zshrc\\."))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist `(,pattern . sh-mode)))
```

Comment: Why is this syntax necessary/why doesn’t `(cons pattern 'sh-mode)` work?

Comment: Oh, sorry, `(cons pattern 'sh-mode)` does work. All this time I was missing the last closing parenthesis and trying to execute just the `(add-to-list…)` bit directly, so of course `pattern` would be undefined for me xD.